# Remove textbox lines contains less value or greather value VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

how can i do a code to remove values <1 and values greater than> 80?

Textbox1.Lines

```
2
11
-1
82
73
11 
12
13
14
15
```

> Expected Output:

```
2
11
73
11
12
13
14
15
```

Why didn't work.

```
If TextBox1.Lines.Contains < 1 Then
TextBox1.Lines(0).String.Empty
ElseIf TextBox1.Lines.Contains > 80 Then
TextBox1.Lines(0).String.Empty
End if.
```

Comment: `TextBox1.Lines = TextBox1.Lines.Where(Function(n) CInt(n) >= 1 AndAlso CInt(n) <= 80).ToArray()`

Comment: integer to string not valid.

Comment: I don't know what that means. If you wrote, e.g., `CInt(n) >= 1` it's Ok, if you instead wrote `CInt(n) >= "1"` then it's not OK.

Comment: ok you changed thanks. I'll try now. so my code will work into a textbox line, which is how I presented it in the template above.

Comment: I didn't change anything. I suggested how to use/not use that method.

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

Comment: I have the first line of the free textbox, because of that it may not work. What should I do?

Comment: If you have empty lines in your TextBox, this detail must be part of the question. Change it to `TextBox1.Lines = TextBox1.Lines.Where(Function(n) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(n) AndAlso (CInt(n) > 1 AndAlso CInt(n) <= 80)).ToArray()` to handle empty lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let us look up what the `.Contains` method expects. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.8
`Public Function Contains (value As String) As Boolean` Ah ha! It expects a string and returns True or False.
Now, let us look at the first line of your code
`If TextBox1.Lines.Contains < 1 Then` I don't see parenthesis containing a string so the method can't work. You are dealing with strings in a TextBox. `.Lines` are strings, `.Contains` expects a string. You can't compare an Integer to a string.

Code Explanation:

Use a StringBuilder. Every time you "change" a string the application must throw away the old string and create an entirely new string. When you are doing this at least 10 times you want to save all that thrashing about by using a StringBuilder which is mutable (changeable).

The string in the line must be converted to an Integer so we can compare it to another Integer. The AndAlso is a short circuit meaning if the first condition is False it doesn't bother checking the second condition. This is a smidge faster.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For Each line In TextBox1.Lines
        If CInt(line) > 1 AndAlso CInt(line) < 80 Then
            sb.AppendLine(line)
        End If
    Next
    TextBox2.Text = sb.ToString
End Sub
```